Semantic UI React Select dropdown not closing
Since a few days, our web app using React 16.14 with Semantic UI React (v.2.0.3) shows a strange behavior: When I select an option from the opening dropdown, the option is selected but the dropdown remains open.
This only happens on Windows 11 machines with Google Chrome v.127.0.6533.120 (64 bit). On Firefox and Edge everything works normally.


<Form.Field data-test="FilterFormFieldSelect">
  <Select
    value={data.fieldName}
    search
    onChange={handleOnChangeField}
    options={fields.map(item => ({
      value: item.name,
      text: item.label,
      content: item.content,
      icon: item.listIcon,
    }))}
  />
</Form.Field>

const handleOnChangeField = (e, target) => {
  const newField = getField(target.value);
  const sameFormType = newField.formType.name === formType.name;

  setData({
    fieldName: target.value,
    value: sameFormType ? data.value : newField.defaultValue,
    error: false,
  });
};



I already tried the following solution approaches, all without success:

find dropdown element and remove “visible” class manually
call handleOnChangeField twice to force a re-render
call setData({...data})
rewrite handler: onChange={(e, target) => handleOnChangeField(e, target)}

Does anybody have similar issues with React / Semantic UI components, or knows about recent Google Chrome changes on class updates in the DOM tree?

We saw the same issue. Once we updated to the latest chrome version it was corrected. Version 128.0.6613.85
